# Как выйти из этого сайта?

Tags: поддержка, аутентификация

Не вижу ссылки/кнопки *exit* или *logout*.
И даже в справке ответа нет :(

Comment: Нажать на StackExchange слева вверху, потом нажать на "выйти" в строке "StackOverflow на русском".

Comment: А просто закрыть вкладку рука не поднимается?

Comment: @avp, тогда другой открывший будет залогинен:)

Comment: @Grundy, серьезно? Я как-то это совсем не понял. Ну, я в браузере убил вкладку, как в тот же контекст кто-то может попасть?

Comment: @avp, ну куки-то остались

Comment: @Grundy, и что? В моем компе остались куки. Дальше что?

Comment: @avp, дальше за комп садится кто-то другой, открывает вкладу и залогинен :)

Comment: @Grundy, я не утверждаю, что это невозможно, но я не умею открывать убитые вкладки. А что, при logout куки удаляются?

Comment: @avp, ага, их сам сервер удаляет

Comment: @Grundy потому что надо выходить из сеанса ОС. Зачем вообще люди сидят семьями под одним юзером? Это ж банально неудобно...

Comment: какой-то очень толстый троллинг)

Comment: @Crystal, никакого толстого троллинга, просто на большинстве сайтов кнопка "Выйти" ни в каком меню не спрятана и её легко найти. Я сам однажды столкнулся с такой проблемой - с трудом отыскал кнопку "Выйти" на SO. В общем спрятали её знатно.

Comment: Вы же хардкорные разработчики, можно было открыть консоль и в элементах страницы посмотреть :) Нашлось сразу же ;))

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- Перейдите по ссылке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
- Также можете выйти и таким образом (иконка в правом верхнем углу):

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  Думаю, дальше разберетесь :)

Comment: А чем качественнее-то? ;)

Comment: Ваше изображение было с зумом, что искажало само видение рисунка :D

Comment: зум пропорции не искажает, к тому же то был векторный зум, без потери качества.